# Functional equation and constant functions

Tags: zeta-functions

I ask about this claim:
let $f$ be an entire function satisfying $f(s)=u(s)f(a-s)$. Assume that $s$ and $a-s$ are not zeroes of $f$ and $f (bar)(a-s)=f(s)$ in a region $D$ ($f(bar)$ is the conjugate of $f$). Then the module of $f(s)/f(bar)(a-s)$ is equal to $1$, implying that the module of $u(s)$ is also $1$. The question is: Does this result implies that in fact the function $u(s)$ is constant.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by the conjugate of $f$.
I see two options: either it is $s\mapsto \overline{f(s)}$ or it is $\bar f$ with 
$\bar f(s)=\overline{f(\bar s)}$.
In the first case, $f$ must be holomorphic and antiholomorphic, hence constant.
In the second case, $f(s)=e^{is}$ and $u(s)=e^{-2is}$ with $a=0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, it is the first case. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please use TeX in your questions.

Comment: Where I can find it

Comment: See the "How to write math" box in the right-lower corner of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the answer is yes $u(s)=1$.

However, for a quite boring reason (as hinted at in the comment of Xogn Ambandl):

If $\overline{f(a-s)}=f(s)$, then $2 \  \Re{f}(s)$ would be holomorphic in that region, as it is equal to $f(s)+\overline{f(s)}= f(s) + f(a-s)$ a sum of holomorphic functions. Yet, then 
as a *real-valued* holomorphic function $\Re{f}(s)$ is constant. And, so $f(s)$ is constant.

Thus, the only functions $f$ fulfilling your assumptions are constant functions, for which what you ask about is clear.

Comment: But I speak about the modulus of u(s). See this link for a similar answer:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85351/possible-locations-for-non-trivial-zeroes-lying-off-the-critical-line
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by you speak about the modulus of u(s), the function u(s) is always equal to 1, what more do you expect to say about it? I tried to explain that the only function f satisfying your condition is a *constant* function. So f(u)=f(v) for any u,v whatsoever and therefore of course your u(s) is always 1 because in fact f(s) = f(a-s)  for f  that satisfies the other condition f(s) = f(bar)(a-s). 

Comment: You are welcome.  