# $\zeta(x)$ in terms of $\zeta'(x),\zeta'(1-x),\Gamma,\psi$

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

By differentiating $\xi$ and solving for $\zeta(1-x)$:

$$ \zeta(1-x) = \frac{2(\zeta'(x)\Gamma(x/2)+\Gamma((1-x)/2) \zeta'(1-x)\pi^{x-1/2})  )}{\Gamma((1-x)/2) \pi^{-1/2+x}(2\log\pi -\psi((1-x)/2)-\psi(x/2))} \qquad (1)$$

and unless the denominator vanishes (like near $\frac12 \pm 6 i$) the non-trivial zeros of zeta are the zeros of

$$\zeta'(x)\Gamma(x/2)+\Gamma((1-x)/2) \zeta'(1-x)\pi^{x-1/2} = 0$$

> Is something similar possible for Riemann $\xi$ or symmetrized zeta $\zeta^*$?

Comment: @Joro. Did you notice that your formula for the non-trivial zeros does also induce a zero at $\frac12 \pm 6.289835989i...$? I believe this is the value where: $|\chi(s)|=|2^s \pi^{s-1}\sin(\pi s/2) \Gamma(1-s)|=1$ when $\Re(s) \rightarrow \frac12$. See here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85351/possible-locations-for-non-trivial-zeroes-lying-off-the-critical-line

Comment: @Agno Thank you. At 6.28... the denominator is zero too, so it cancels. I suppose this is not possible for other values, not sure.

Comment: @Agno edited because of your comment. (1) doesn't induce zero there because of $0/0$.

Comment: @Agno the plots always coincide, here is a plot on the critical line:  http://s23.postimg.org/ktoyver0b/zeta_via_deriv.png

Comment: @joro. Nice formula indeed! You now have $\zeta(1-x)$ fully expressed in terms of its derivatives. Did you try converting it to $\zeta(s)$ using $\zeta(1-x)=\dfrac{\zeta(x)}{\chi(x)}$? What is immediately clear from the formula is that $\zeta'(x)$ and $\zeta'(1-x)$ cannot both be zero at the same time, unless this coincides with a (non)-trivial zero of $\zeta(x)$ or they are annihilated by the denominator. 

Comment: Writing $x=1/2+it$, the formula is equivalent to $1=\pi^{it}\dfrac{\Gamma(1/4-it/2)\zeta'(1/2-it)}{\Gamma(1/4+it/2)\zeta'(1/2+it)}$. Does this imply that $t$ is real?

Comment: Read $-1$ instead of $1$ in the previous comment.

Comment: Write $F(t)=\pi^{it}\dfrac{\Gamma(1/4-it/2)\zeta'(1/2-it)}{\Gamma(1/4+it/2)\zeta'(1/2+it)}$. $\zeta(1/2+i\tau)=0$ iff $F(\tau)=-1$. But $F(-t)=1/F(t)$ hence $F(t)=e^{ikt}$ for real $k$. So $\zeta(1/2+i\tau)=0$ implies $\tau$ is real.

Comment: @Agno: Your suggestion simplifies to $0$ if I have done it correctly.

Comment: @Agno on the critical line there is simpler formula, check http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134981/differential-equation-for-zeta-on-the-critical-line